# AutoGenerateInsertButton in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, properties

I have the following GridView

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
      OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="Chart_Id" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" >

      <Columns>
          <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="False" ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowInsertButton="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Week" HeaderText="Week" SortExpression="Week" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Host" HeaderText="Host" SortExpression="Host" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic_1" HeaderText="Topic 1" SortExpression="Topic_1" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic_2" HeaderText="Topic 2" SortExpression="Topic_2"
                            HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic_3" HeaderText="Topic 3" SortExpression="Topic_3" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic_4" HeaderText="Topic 4" SortExpression="Topic_4" />
      </Columns>


 </asp:GridView>
```

By default, I have the edit/insert/cancel buttons set to false.

Then in the code behind, I want to be able to set these to true during certain conditions.

```
    string theUser = Helpers.GetUser();
    string admin = "adminName";

    if (theUser == admin) {

       // Set the buttons to true  

    }
```

I've been looking for ways to do this, and someone suggested to use the AutoGenerate properties, and then enable them like so:

```
 GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
 GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
 GridView1.AutoGenerateInsertButton = true; // This one throws an error
```

Only problem is, AutogenerateInsertButton does not seem to exist, in the main ASPX page or in the code behind.

Can anyone suggest some ways for me to access these properties and set them to true?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that a GridView has a `AutoGenerateInsertButton` property? A `GridView` is a list of rows, where each row represents a record/element/item which can be edited or deleted. But it doesn't make sense do have a insert-button **for each record** because it already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think that a GridView should have an `AutoGenerateInsertButton` property?

A `GridView` is a list of `GridViewRows`, where each row represents a record/element/item which can be edited or deleted. But it doesn't make sense to have a insert-button **for each record** because it already exists.

You could follow [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/inserting-a-new-record-from-the-gridview-s-footer-vb) which shows how to use the footer-row of the `GridView` to insert a new record.

Comment: I see. I'll check out the footer-row method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The property `AutoGenerateInsertButton` exists on the [`DetailsView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.autogenerateinsertbutton.aspx).  Whoever designed the control probably figured that you don't need an insert button for each row in the grid, since each would essentially do the same thing.

So, maybe you could display an empty DetailsView at the bottom of the grid, or just create your own insert command using a regular Button.